# Live USB won't boot when corrupted hard disk is also inserted

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I'm trying to see the content of a possibly corrupted hard disk so I'm booting ubuntu through live USB to check the hard disk as I don't have an external hard drive cable connector.

This is a problem I face a lot. Live Ubuntu boots fine when no hard disks are connected and also when a working hard disk is connected. But not when a corrupted hard disk is connected. The problem isn't from the PC as the same happens on all the PCs I test this on.

It just boots to a black screen.

Booting to live Ubuntu then inserting the disk won't work as only the hard disks inserted at boot get recognized so I'm forced to boot while the disk is connected if I want to view its content.

Comment: So can't you connect the HD after the USB has booted?

Comment: If I connect an internal HD after ubuntu boots it wouldn't be recognized.